# Library version conflicts in .NET: System.Net.Http

Tags: .net, nuget

I am trying to use NuGet Package Manager Console to deploy changes to the database. When I issue the `Update-Database` command, it fails with an error message saying:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.1,
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
  dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My projects targets .NET 4.5.2 which as far as I can tell, provides `System.Net.Http` in version `4.0.0.0`. Thus, the incriminated library is not laid in the binary output directory. When I download the `4.1.1.1` version (NuGet package version 4.3.2) and copy it into the binary output directory, along with my DLLs, I get another error message:

```
Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other
  instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
```

In both cases the exception is `System.IO.FileLoadException` and it is thrown in `Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient'1.CreateRootHandler()`. I checked the source code of that function and it in fact references .NET 4.5 and `System.Net.Http`:

```
  protected static HttpClientHandler CreateRootHandler()
  {
    // Create our root handler
#if NET45
    return new WebRequestHandler();
#else
    return new HttpClientHandler();
#endif
  }
```

However, nowhere I can find the exact version number of `System.Net.Http`. Finally, I used ILSpy to inspect `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime` and it seems to depend on `System.Net.Http` in version `4.0.0.0`.

[image: ILSpy inspection into Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime]

I have also tried removing all references to `System.Net.Http` and installing the newest NuGet (4.3.2). That lead to subsequent errors with missing methods:

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient..ctor(
  AuthenticationCallback, System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[])'.
```

and

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1..ctor(
  System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[])'.
```

which I solved by copying the right DLL from the respective NuGet into the deployment directory. This finally leads back to:

```
Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other
  instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am having the same issue right now, and I've tried plenty of potential solutions I found on the web but none seems to work...

Comment: Nope, but I used the migrate.exe that comes with entity framework and that unblocked deploying changes to the database. I think visual studio is still blocked (that is, the package manager console) but I simply don't care anymore.

Answer (score 1):

After finding that Kunal's answer here:

[MongoDB client throws a FileNotFoundException in mscorlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368208/mongodb-client-throws-a-filenotfoundexception-in-mscorlib)

worked for me, I tried changing the version number for System.Net.Http.  I have the System.Net.Http version 4.3.3 installed targeting net462 and this worked for me:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```